# Where can I find the Official File Hierarchy Standard for UNIX?

Tags: fhs, standard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Resources to learn linux architecture in detail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5977/resources-to-learn-linux-architecture-in-detail)

I migrated to UNIX (Linux, Ubuntu) and I'm trying to understand the organisation of files and directories. I stumbled upon [File Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) (quite old it seems) and it made me wonder if this is the ACTUAL standard that is used.

Also may I ask if additional links to resources to broaden my knowledge (and everyone that asks questions about FHS) on these wonderful NIX* environments.

Comment: That is the standard. The fact that it looks quite old is a measure of it's success as a standard...

Comment: Awesome, the confusing thing is that said website has some links to Enya music and that made me doubt if it was the official or some kind of investigation made by someone else. Gotta love standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here it is: [The FHS 2.3 Specification](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/)

Comment: As with all things unix, it's less of a law and more of a guideline; how much of it is adhered to varies by distro and flavor...