# About the status of the File Hierarchy standard

Tags: filenames, fhs

In the question [Where can I find the Official File Hierarchy Standard for UNIX?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19225/where-can-i-find-the-official-file-hierarchy-standard-for-unix) one writes:

```
As with all things unix, it's less of a law and more of a guideline;
how much of it is adhered to varies by distro and flavor...
```

It is also said

```
That is the standard. The fact that it looks quite old 
is a measure of it's success as a standard...
```

What is the status today? Which Linux distributions take the [FHS standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.pdf) seriously and which do not?

Comment: IIRC FHS is part of LSB, so LSB compliance might be used to see if a distro takes FHS seriously: https://www.linuxbase.org/lsb-cert/productdir.php?by_lsb